# Javascript Inheritance subclass calling by default

Tags: javascript, inheritance

I have a scenario in which i need to override sample.A in sample.B

and when i click i will call a function from which i  need to call sample.A.Test() which need to internally call the overridden function(Test) in sample.B and execute only this function. is it possible ?

My peers told that java script will call the subclass function  by default and get executed, is it true?

The above scenario

```
sample.A = (function () {

return {

Test: function(){           
    console.debug('Test in Super class');
},
}

sample.B = (function () {
return {

Test: function(){   
    console.debug('Test in Sub class');
},
}
```

can this behavior be achieved through java script or jquery?

Comment: jQuery is just another JavaScript library, and does nothing you would need for inheritance.

Comment: What do you need those function-expression-closures for (which even lack a `)();` in the end, making your code invalid)? Just assign the objects to the properties of the `sample` object.

Comment: JavaScript has no classes, but prototypical inheritance. Please show us how you invoke your functions, and why your superclass `A` internally should call its subclass `B`?

Answer (score 0):

To enable 'inheritance' in JavaScript, you at the very least need to add some utility methods.

For instance:

```
function inheritMethods(fromA, intoB) {
   for (x in fromB) {
     if (typeof x === 'function') {
        intoB[x] = fromA[x];
     }
   }
}
```

or something the like ...

But since 'inheritance' in the classical OO sense is not native to JavaScript there are various ways about emulating this. There is a nice discussion in '[JavaScript Patterns](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/9780596806767.do)' under 'Code Reuse' on this, if you can get hold of the book.